# React Tiny Virtual List - Scroll to bottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtualization

Trying to use https://github.com/clauderic/react-tiny-virtual-list to display a list as without it the browser just locks up.

The issue I am having is that I want the focus to stay on the bottom of the list and scroll as more elements get added. There are options for "scrollToIndex" and "scrollToAlignment" but I can't work out how to use them.

The virtual list code is pretty simple and self explanatory, does anyone understand how to use the scroll options to auto scroll to the bottom?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, { transports: ['websocket'] });
    socket.emit('onboarding', { id: uploadId });
    socket.on('transcript_log', function (resp) {
    if (resp.log !== undefined) {
        var currentList = this.state.transcriptList.slice();
        currentList.push(resp.log);
        this.setState({ transcriptList: currentList })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
    <VirtualList
        width='100%'
        height={280}
        itemCount={this.state.transcriptList.length}
        itemSize={20}
        renderItem={({index, style}) =>
          <div key={index} style={style}>
            {this.state.transcriptList[index]}
          </div>
        }
      />
    )
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<VirtualList
    width='100%'
    height={280}
    itemCount={this.state.transcriptList.length}
    itemSize={20}
    scrollToIndex={this.state.index}
    scrollToAlignment='bottom'
    renderItem={({index, style}) =>
      <div key={index} style={style}>
        {this.state.transcriptList[index]}
      </div>
    }
  />
```

And on the parent component (that renders the VirtualList):

```
this.state={
    index: 0 //default to top of list 
}

scrollToBottom(){
   this.setState(() => {
       index: this.state.transcriptList.length - 1
   })
}
```

Then when you call scrollToBottom() the VirtualList should render at the bottom

Comment: Doesn't work, I thought it was always a bad idea to use findDOMNode as well?

Comment: its not a bad idea per se but it is meant to be sort of a last resort

Comment: can you share more code? It'd help me to see the parent component

Comment: you might need to do `this.refs.virtualList` but I don't think so. maybe try `let el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.virtualList)` and then `window.scrollTo(0, el.offsetTop)`  sorry I don't use refs a lot

Comment: Adding more code - im surprised you cant use the scrollToIndex - surely thats the whole point of it?

Comment: I only want the list to scroll to the bottom, not the entire window?

Comment: okay so I just read through the docs, try this, pass in `scrollToAlignment='bottom'` as a prop and then write a method to get the index you want to scroll to and store it in your parent state, then pass it in as a prop `scrollToIndex={this.state.index}` default would be 0, and so focus starts at the top but if you change it to say, 15 it should scroll to the 15th item. Those docs are super unclear but I think that should work

Comment: if you set `this.state.index` to `this.state.transcriptList.length - 1` that would scroll to the bottom element

Comment: So this worked, thanks for the help. The only other thing I had to do was add a blank element into the list at the start otherwise index 0 is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple..

```
scrollToIndex={11}           <= Item index to scroll
scrollToAlignment="end"      <=the top of the container
```

[Here is the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2250y06rn)